# JCombobox disappearing after adding a new panel

Tags: java

Hi guys I am facing a little problem which I couldn't figure out the reason,
I am making a simple chat application in which each Site( in my case a panel in a tabbed pane) can chat with the other sites the problem is that when I add a new panel after the creation of the first ones it makes the JComboboxes of the previous site(panel) disappear as shown in the pictures!
[picture1](http://postimg.org/image/dsarkk2dd/)
[picture2](http://postimg.org/image/sti3yxrep/)

any suggestion I will be thankful

here is the part in which I add a new Item to the JCombobox(there are tow) list
the JCombobox(both of them) is created in an other class and it already has items

```
public class Ajout {
public static void Aj(JButton button, final JTabbedPane tabbedPane){
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            ....
            TP.tb_rem_port.addItem("200"+in);
            ....
            TP.tb_rem_service.addItem("Site"+in);
            ....

        }});

}

 }
```

Comment: I suggest showing your code in the form of a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It is hard to find anything, however for me it seems that you just try to add one single JComboBox object to multiple panels. After [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) : "Each GUI component can be contained only once. If a component is already in a container and you try to add it to another container, the component will be removed from the first container and then added to the second"

Comment: @m.cekiera the idea is that I am creating one JCombobox in which I add the site port number's for each site, in the first ones I am using a loop (for the button créer) and it worms perfectly but when I come to add a new one which means add a new item to the JCombobox list I get the issue

Comment: The code is too complicated, if you expect to get a answer, you should post a MCVE example, as suggested above.